# Android app shows default android icon in some devices

Tags: android, icons

I upload an app in play store.Now i got a comment that it shows default android icon in some devices (galaxy s4,nexus 5 )instead of app icon.I placed app icon in drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi,drawable-xhpdi and drawable-tvdpi. Default android icon is present outside resource folder as ic_launcher-web. While testing it showed the app icon itself in galaxy s4.But when it downloaded from play store it is showing default app icon.What I should do to correct this problem?

Comment: Maybe my mistake, but what about `drawable-xxhdpi`?

Comment: i didn't add any icon in that folder.

Answer (score 4):

Since app icon has very little impact on the system performance, I recommend that you to put a 256*256 icon in the default /res/drawable/ resource folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the issue was with app icon resource.

I had defined an adaptive icon in a `mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder. Both for standard and round resources. For other devices I had standard launcher icon in respective `mipmap-<density-qualifier>`. And in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

The default icon was displayed on Devices that had lower version of Android than 26 but launcher supported `roundIcon`. Cause this resource was not existing for this devices. Add `ic_launcher_round`resource for all densities solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the app icon in `drawable-xxhdpi` and `drawable-xxxhdpi` too.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: not worked my app icon run on sumsung j7 but not show on s8 plus