# app shows default icon on some device but not other

Tags: android, apk

I created a android app apk and tried it on 3 android phones:

- Galaxy S4 (Android 5.0.1)
- ZTE Avid Plus (Android 5.1.1)
- Huawei Mate 9 (Android 8.0, Oreo)

the app icon on the first two devices shows what I expected: a customized graphical icon; however the app icon shows a default robot icon on Huawei Mate 9.

I did search through this site and I found these relevant posts:

- [default robot icon instead of app icon after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45141488/default-robot-icon-instead-of-app-icon-after-installation)
- [Android app shows default android icon in some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535249/android-app-shows-default-android-icon-in-some-devices)

I tried to follow the instructions there but it still failed.

BTW, I noticed some apps also show default icon occasionally on Huawei Mate 9, apps such as reddit and whatsApp.

Comment: Try to change your customized launcher icon name and update the AndroidManifest.xml? Sometimes the default name (@drawable/ic_launcher) has been put in other libraries in some specific folders

Comment: When a launcher requests an app icon, the framework returns either `android:icon` or `android:roundIcon`, depending on the device build configuration. read more about [Round Icon Resources](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1)